# AJAX request to verify reCaptcha failed/cancelled, claims missing params

Tags: jquery, ajax, recaptcha

I am trying to verify a reCaptcha with jQuery and it's not going through.

When I check chrome's dev tools network tab, the request to verify gets cancelled with no response. I can see in the form data both of the required fields being passed in successfully (response and secret). I also unable to log an error message at this point.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#contact-submit').on('click', function() {
    var captchaResponse = grecaptcha.getResponse();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify",
      // dataType: 'jsonp',
      data: {
        secret: "SECRETKEY",
        response: captchaResponse
      }
      // ,
      // success: function(data) {
      //   console.log('suc?: ' + data);
      // },
      // error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      //   console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
      //   console.log(textStatus);
      //   console.log(errorThrown);
      // }
    })
    // .done(function(res) { ... });
  });
});
```

Comment: What do you get in your error / success callback of ajax ?

Comment: success doesn't log anything, only the first XMLHttpRequest logs anything in the error, Object {readyState: 0, responseText: "", status: 0, statusText: "error"}

Comment: Look's like there is some valid error thrown  from google.you may need to check out the google api docs for the same

Comment: BTW what is the logged for `errorThrown` ? This would give you more detail about the error

Comment: there is nothing from errorThrown. If I uncomment the dataType: jsonp, the XMLHttprequest goes away as well, but there is still nothing logging from success.

Comment: any update on this?